# Definir auto height en UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitableview

Hay alguna forma de que el alto de un `UICollectionViewCell` se adapte al contenido como en el `UITableViewCell`??

Ejemplo:
En el `UITableViewCell` tengo este código para que el alto se adapte al contenido:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250.0
```

Como puedo hacer para que en las celdas del `UICollectionViewCell` tambien funcione igual??

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las celdas de tipo `UICollectionViewCell` funciona exactamente igual que el `UITableViewCell`. Lo más importante es que el las constraints del `Autolayout` estén correctamente configuradas.

Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que acostumbra a funcionar solo con los controles de texto.